# How to Send SOAPMessage into JMS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jms

Inside my web service application, I need to send a SOAPMessage to JMS Queue. Searching in the  net for a while, i got this piece of code:

```
Message message =MessageTransformer.SOAPMessageIntoJMSMessage(soapMessage, session);
```

For this line to work, `com.sun.messaging.xml.MessageTransformer` import is required. Now I am not able to download the required jar for this. Help me getting this jar or let me know if there is another way to this.

Comment: Try googling for 'find jar'. You will see miracles happen.

Answer (score 3):

You can find it at the [**Open Message Queue**](http://mq.java.net/javadoc/4.5/javadoc/com/sun/messaging/xml/package-summary.html) library. Since it's a Glassfish component,  if you are deploying your code into this server, you just have to check if the "mq" Jar is at your classpath. If you  are using other server, you *could* find some incompatibilities (I don't know for sure).

Anyway, it wouldn't be that hard to get a SOAP message payload and write it down as a JMS message payload. This way, you wouldn't need to add another dependency to your Java project.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following site for finding/downloading a missing jar

http://www.findjar.com/index.x